# Post from GCP Pub Sub to on-prem Kafka

Tags: google-cloud-platform, apache-kafka

I have a requirement to publish messages from Google Pub/Sub topic to a Kafka running on my on-prem infrastructure. I stumbled on this link.

https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/kafka-connect-gcp-pubsub/index.html

This should work. Wanted to know if you've used any other alternative solution to achieve this?

Comment: what do you expect as alternative? There is no native connector between Kafka and Pubsub. So you need to have an intermediary process that link the both worlds. It can be a compute engine, a cloud functions, your on prem servers (...) you need a compute stuff to achieve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to integrate `PubSub` and `Kafka` I suggest that you create a script for this purpose. In `Python` for example we have libraries for both [PubSub](https://googleapis.dev/python/pubsub/latest/index.html) and [Kafka](https://pypi.org/project/kafka-python/)

Based on that, you could create a script more or less like below and run it inside some processing resource like **Compute Engine** or in your on premises server:

```
from google.cloud import pubsub_v1
from kafka import KafkaProducer


def callback(message):
     print(message.data)
     producer.send('<your-topic>', message.data)
     message.ack()


producer = KafkaProducer(bootstrap_servers='localhost:1234')  //Change it for your real parameter

subscription_name = "projects/<your-project>/subscriptions/<your-subscription>"
subscriber = pubsub_v1.SubscriberClient()

future = subscriber.subscribe(subscription_name, callback)
```